# BeautifulSoup как спарсить элементы внутри блока?

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Ситуация следующая. Есть повторяющие span с класами unit unit_temperature_c и unit unit_temperature_f в которых находяться температуры на разные дни. И есть один блок в котором находяться те же спаны которые отвечают за температуру на даный момент что мне и нужно спарсить. Но... как заставить спарсить отдельно температуру по цельсию и отдельно по фаренгейту?

```
temperatura = soup.find('div', class_='now-weather').text

<div class="now-weather">
<span class="unit unit_temperature_c">
<span class="sign">+</span>19
<span class="lower">,4</span>
 </span>
<span class="unit unit_temperature_f">
<span class="sign"></span>
67</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я верно понял задачу, то нужно использовать метод find_all в нужном блоке и дальше искать нужные теги.

```python
temperature_all = soup.find_all('div', class_='now-weather')

for temperature in temperature_all:
    temp_c = soup.find('span', class_='unit unit_temperature_c')
    temp_f = soup.find('span', class_='unit unit_temperature_f')

    print(f'Температура в цельсиях: {temp_c.text}')
    print(f'Температура по фаренгейту: {temp_f.text}')
```

Comment: А как такое распарсить

<div class="now-info-item wind">
<div class="item-title">Вітер</div>
<div class="item-value">
<div class="unit unit_wind_m_s">3
<div class="item-measure">
<div>м/c</div>
<div>ПнС</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="unit unit_wind_km_h">11<div class="item-measure"><div>км/год</div><div>ПнС</div></div></div></div></div>

Где мне нужно только 3 м/c ПнС

Comment: Все по той же схеме:       items = soup.find-all('div', class_='now-info-item wind')   for item in items:  info = soup.find ('div', class_='unit_wind_m_s').text     print(info)

Comment: winter_div = soup_gismetio.find('div', class_='unit_wind_m_s')
    winter_unit = []
    for item in winter_div.select('.item-measure > div'):    
        winter_unit += item
    winter_div = winter_div.text.split(winter_unit[0]+winter_unit[1])

в общем решил проблему так...